# Visual Studio web application deployment to IIS with Oracle.DataAcces.dll

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I have been trying to deploy a web app using Oracle.DataAcces.dll.
The web server has 64-bit Oracle Client installed and I use 32-bit because Visual Studio requires it.
When the app is deployed to the server I get the following error.
Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

After researching, I decided to set the Oracle.DataAcces.dll reference to Copy Local=false in Visual Studio.  That way the 32-bit Oracle.DataAcces.dll would not wind up in the web app's bin folder and the web app would use the 64-bit version on the server.  And my Platform Target is set to Any CPU.

However, that caused the same error.  So if anyone knows the answer to that, please help... I don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I set the Oracle.DataAcces.dll reference to Copy Local=false
and changed the *.csproj file reference from

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86" />
```

to

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are working on a 64-bit Windows "AnyCPU" means your application will run in 64-bit mode - even for debugging, no matter if your Visual Studio is an 32-bit application.

This requires also an Oracle Client and the ODP.NET provider both in 64-bit version.

That is the reason why your reference `<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86" />` does not work, it forces to load the 32-bit ODP.NET.

You can write the reference simply as

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess" >
   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
   <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

`<Private>False</Private>` maps to `Copy Local=false` in Visual Studio GUI.

With this reference it should work in each case, on your local machine and on your target server, no matter if you compile to "x86", "x64" or "AnyCPU". You can change even the .NET Framework to another version,e.g. `.NET Framework 2.0` without doing any change in your code. All this works provided the appropriate Oracle Client and ODP.NET are properly installed, i.e. architecture (32bit vs. 64bit) must match and major release of ODP.NET (1.x or 2.0 or 4.0) must match .NET Framework major release.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried... I'll try your suggestion.